# How to get and set the transparent npm proxy for a Visual Studio 2015 ASP.net 5 project

Tags: npm, nuget, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

The packages in my `project.json` uses the `node package manager`. I add a new package via `nuget` to my `Visual Studio 2015` `ASP.NET 5` Beta 8 project.

When I'm on my home internet I can get download packages. However when I'm at the office I get the following error in my console if I add a new package:

> PATH=.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
>   C:\Users\USERNAME.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8\bin\dnx.exe "C:\Users\USERNAME.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8\bin\lib\Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling\Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.dll" restore "C:\PROJFOLDER\PROJNAME" -f "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\DNU"
>   Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-beta8-15858
>
> GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='AutoMapper'
>   Error: FindPackagesById: AutoMapper
>      An error occurred while sending the request.

In Visual Studio 2015 Solution Explorer:

[image]

I get:

> Package restore failed

If I use `nuget` in a classic class library that doesn't use `npm` then I am able to download the same packages, so the issue seem to limited to `npm`

On researching the error it is listed as an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/451#issuecomment-99160969). 
A workaround listed on the issue is to set a Windows environmental variables to my corporate proxy.

However I don't have proxy settings set in Internet Explorer.

[image]

My questions:

1. How do I determine the proxy I am using?
2. Is there an alternative way I can get it to work other than setting the environment variables. I tried the dnx.config workaround but it didn't work.
3. I use the laptop both at work and home. Is their a solution where I don't have to change settings between office and home?

Answer (score 6):

If your internet works through Internet Explorer  you can just add  the following section to the machine.config located in the folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config`

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

If you get a permission error saving the file, save it to your desktop and copy it from there back to the original location.